# Later Defining variable (else: NullPointerException)

Tags: android, variables, arraylist, overwrite

I have an ArrayList, which is defined in one function, and gets called in another one. But when I add `public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` at the beginning, then run a function that adds items to that list and then try to call `list` in another function, it overwrites the previous set and just returns an empty list.
But when I just have `public ArrayList<String> list;` at the beginning, again add items in one function and then try to use `list`, it throws a NullPointerException.
I also tried having `ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` in the onCreate method, but that's a NPE too.

So one function is just

```
public void setList() {    
   for(int x=0; x<=5;x++){
      list.add(Integer.toString(x));
   }
}
```

(the `Integer.toString(x)` is currently just for testing)
 And the Other one is

```
public void setList() {
   Log.d("Log",list.toString());
}
```

At the very beginning after `public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {`
I have tried

```
public ArrayList<String> list; //this throws a NPE
```

and

```
public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //this overwrites the variable each time it's called
```

How do I fix that?

Could the issue be that I change the displayed Fragment after the set method and before the get method is called?

Thank you very much

Comment: Can you show us your code? the description is a bit confusing.

Comment: sounds like you need just another list? - yeah actually code would be helpful.

Comment: Can you include more code? We need to see where the list is declared.

Comment: If you modify the same list at the same time, you can use a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue` or you can use `syncronized(list)` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 1 list object at the top of the code and do not create new ones in the functions. It should look like this.

```
public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

// onCreate....

public void addElement() {
   for(int x=0; x<=5;x++){
       list.add(Integer.toString(x));
   }
}

public void showElements() {
    Log.d("Log",list.toString());
}
```

Comment: That's where it just gives me an empty list. But, as just added to the question, could the issue be that I change the displayed Fragment after the set method and before the get method is called?

Comment: if you are creating a new display fragment yes. in that case you can use public static ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();    to persist the data.